# A more efficient method of building a prime array for a beginner

Tags: java, performance

Good morning. I just completed my first course in JAVA and was looking for projects online to keep things fresh for the summer. I stumbled on the project Euler website and am trying to complete problem 10. I wrote this algorithm to build an array of prime numbers, and it worked for previous problems in the set. However, when I try to run it for numberOfPrimes = 100000 or larger, it takes several minutes.

I am assuming there is a more efficient method, although I may not have the skills to understand it. I would appreciate any advice either way.

```
        int[] arrayOfPrimes = new int[numberOfPrimes];
        arrayOfPrimes[0] = 2;


        for(int i = 1; i < numberOfPrimes; i++)
        {
            int n = arrayOfPrimes[(i - 1)] + 1;


            for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            {
                if(n % arrayOfPrimes[j] == 0)
                {
                    n++;
                    j = -1; //resets to 0 at the next iteration.
                }
            }

            arrayOfPrimes[i] = n;
        }
```

Comment: j can stop at i/2

Comment: Sorry, Euler philosophy is "If you can't solve it, you can't solve it". Read your way through that yourself, please.

Comment: Perhaps something like Sieve of Eratosthenes (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) or Sieve of Atkin (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Atkin) would help you to reconsider your approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its best to use ArrayLists which you can manipulate easier and take as many numbers as you want here try this code :-

```
int numberOfPrimes=100000;

ArrayList<Integer>Primes = new ArrayList<>();

Primes.add(2);

int i=3;
Primes.add(i);
for(int j = 0; j < Primes.size(); j++){//Checks all previous prime numbers before the new number
if(i%Primes.get(j)==0){//Checks if prime number at j is divisible by i

if(Primes.size()>numberOfPrimes){//breaking out of loop after reaching above numberOfPrimes 

Primes.remove(Primes.size()-1);//Removes the last non prime number 
    break;
}
Primes.remove(Primes.size()-1);//Removes the non prime number
j=-1;//resets j to start from 0
i++;//next number
Primes.add(i);//adding it for next check
}
if(j==Primes.size()-2){//Another resting condition when all previous prime numbers are checked
j=-1;
i++;
 Primes.add(i);
}
}
//end

for(int j = 0; j < Primes.size(); j++){// just for printing
System.out.println(Primes.get(j));
}
```

It took about 1 min 7 seconds to achieve 100000 .It uses just 1 for loop the other is to print the array.

Don't forget to insert `import java.util.ArrayList;` at the very top before the class

Comment: I didn't learn about ArrayLists this semester - this post led me down a long rabbit hole of videos and examples online. This class seems incredibly useful, and I wish I would've been taught this sooner. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether the prime that you're trying to devide `n` with is greater than square root of `n`. That should get you till 100,000.

However, there are no methods to get arbitrarily large consecutive array of primes.

Here's the modified code

```
int numberOfPrimes = 100000;
int[] prime = new int[numberOfPrimes];
prime[0] = 2;

for (int i = 1; i < numberOfPrimes; i++) {
    int n = prime[(i - 1)] + 1;

    int sqrtN = (int)(Math.sqrt(n)) + 1;

    for (int j = 0; j < i && prime[j] < sqrtN; j++) {
        if (n % prime[j] == 0) {
            n++;
            j = -1; // resets to 0 at the next iteration.
        }
    }

    prime[i] = n;
}
```